# fail2ban WARNING invalid command on apache2 disabled websites

Tags: debian, fail2ban

I have a problem on a Debian Squeezy webserver running fail2ban. Now and then, fail2ban stops working complaining of missing access.log:

```
fail2ban.comm   : WARNING Invalid command: ['set', 'http-get-dos', 'addlogpath', '/var/www/foo.bar/log/access.log']
```

I have to touch the offending file and restart fail2ban in order to start banning again.

Any suggestion?

[EDIT] Added logrotate.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

Comment: Maybe a logrotate issue? Could you post your logrotate config for this file please?

Comment: Hi @sebix, I have edited my question to add the logrotate.conf. Tell me if you need anything else. Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any other entry for `access.log` in `/etc/logrotate.d/`? Try grep on the directory.